# Hive: calculating running DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

Hi is there a way to calculate running count distinct in HIVE?

I have a data frame that contains date and hours and the id of people that are currently visiting a website.

What I would like to do is to know the "cumulative" count distinct of the
id split by date.

I can not use group by dt, hour, count(distinct id) because if a player
is active at 1 and 2 it will be counted twice.

Is there a way to do this using Hive analytics and windowing?

I have tried:

```
select date, hour, 
      count(distinct id) over( partition by date order by hrs rows between unbounded preceding and current row) users
from db.table
```

but it throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is spot on, Hive just doesn't like counting distinct with windowing functions.  The workaround is collecting to a set and then taking the size of each array over the window.  I made some random data to make sure this is what you want.  Say you had

```
date        hour    user_id
2015-01-01  1       1001
2015-01-01  1       1001
2015-01-01  2       1002
2015-01-01  7       1003
2015-01-02  4       1001
2015-01-02  4       1001
2015-01-02  5       1002
2015-01-03  1       1004
2015-01-03  3       1005
2015-01-03  4       1001
2015-01-03  4       1002
```

**Query**:

```
select date
  , hour
  , size(collect_set(user_id) over (partition by date order by hour
                                    rows between unbounded preceding
                                    and current row)) users
from db.table
```

**Output**:

```
date        hour    users
2015-01-01  1       1
2015-01-01  1       1
2015-01-01  2       2
2015-01-01  7       3
2015-01-02  4       1
2015-01-02  4       1
2015-01-02  5       2
2015-01-03  1       1
2015-01-03  3       2
2015-01-03  4       3
2015-01-03  4       4
```

As far as performance is concerned, this takes ***one*** MR job.  Doing a self-left-outer join is a disaster in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off doing a join with a case when statement.

Then you can do the following easily:

```
select a.date,
  count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (prior_date < date) THEN b.id ELSE NULL END)
from 
my_table a
left outer join
(select date as prior_date, id from my_table) b
 on (1=1)
 where a.date > b.date
;
```

This is a assuming date is string comparable.  You can do that by the following and assuming your dates are all fairly recent so the string are the same size.  Otherwise you might have to lpad the string with zeros.  See below:

Assuming your date and time are like yyyy-MM-dd  and HH:mm:ss, then convert your date and time to unix_time_stamp like this:

```
unix_timestamp(concat_ws(" ", date, time)) as date
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but I would like to do it with a window function.. and would like to know why my syntax is wrong?

Comment: I think it is because windowing functions require an aggregate function.  The use of count(dinstinct(column))  over (...) wraps an aggregation function around the distinct operator.  The distinct operator is not an aggegation function so distrinct(column) over (...) fails. Good luck lucacerone! :)